# Cannot cast array from dtype('O') on read_csv pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm try to load a csv using a mappings dict, and forcing pandas to read string/object columns as `category` type to be more efficient with memory usage (reading a large csv file).

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter=',', quotechar='~', escapechar='\0',usecols=cols,dtype=dtypes))
```

`dtypes` is a dict where I have changed all the fields which pandas naturally reads as `object` dtype to `category`.

On attempting to read, I encounter the error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>   pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Is there a way to force pandas to convert these fields to `category` type, or to narrow down on which field is causing the problem?

Remainder of the stack trace:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         3     df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter=',', quotechar='~', escapechar='\0',usecols=cols,dtype=dtypes)
>         4 else:
>   ----> 5     df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter=',', quotechar='~', escapechar='\0',usecols=cols,nrows=nrows,dtype=dtypes)
>         6 
>         7 print ('read complete',df.shape,datetime.now() - startTime)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
>       707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       708 
>   --> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       710 
>       711     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       453 
>       454     try:
>   --> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       456     finally:
>       457         parser.close()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
>      1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
>      1068 
>   -> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>      1070 
>      1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
>      1837     def read(self, nrows=None):
>      1838         try:
>   -> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>      1840         except StopIteration:
>      1841             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in >pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in >pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in >pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ManualSaved'

Comment: All you dtypes sample

Comment: Can you include the code for your dtypes dictionary?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for us to review